# Negation - Cauchy sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that $(x_i)_{i \geq 1}$ is not a Cauchy sequence of real numbers.

How to prove that there exist $\varepsilon >0 $ and an increasing sequence $(i_n)$ of indices such that
$$
|x_{i_{n+1}}-x_{i_n}|\geq \varepsilon
$$
for any $n \geq 1$?

Comment: First, write down what it means for a sequence to not be Cauchy (the negation of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition). Then construct your sequence inductively.

Comment: I understand very well the strategy. How can I do the induction?

Comment: There is an $\epsilon>0$ so that given any $N$, there are $n,m>N$ with $|x_n-x_m|\ge\epsilon$. Note that, then, given any $x_N$, there must be an $M>N$ with $|x_N-x_M|\ge\epsilon/2$ (otherwise, by the triangle inequality $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$). So, construct the sequence with "separation distance" $\epsilon/2$.